# Как обработать данные в form.cleaned_data используя ModelForm или создать кастомный валидатор? Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

всех любителей django!
В процессе изучения, столкнулся с проблемой.

Ситуация следующая:

Делаю страницу изменения данных авторизованного пользователя: "имя" и "email". И если пользователь меняет, допустим "имя", а поле "email" оставляет пустым, то поле "email" перезаписывается на пустое значение и наоборот. В моем случае это всего два поля, но их может быть и 10 на одной странице, поэтому проблема выглядит актуальной.

Придумал два решения, все они проверяют: если передается пустое значение, то берем существующие данные.
(мб это решение кривое, но какое есть ;)

1. Пробую изменить данные через **cleaned_data** во **vews**:

```
def user_profile_edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileEdit(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        username = request.user.username
        useremail = request.user.email
        if form.is_valid():
            if not form.cleaned_data['username']:
                form.cleaned_data['username'] = username
            if not form.cleaned_data['email']:
                form.cleaned_data['email'] = useremail
            form.save()
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'Профиль изменен.')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Ошибка!')
            return redirect('edit')
    else:
        form = UserProfileEdit()

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, template_name='user/editprofile.html', context=context)
```

Данные в **cleaned_data** меняются, но пустые данные уже оказываются в модели, хотя мне казалось, что это делает **form.save()**

Была мысль сделать несвязанную с моделью форму, но тогда  не очень понятно, как передать во vews экземпляр текущего пользователя, для изменений. (для экземпляра **ModelForm** я указываю его как **instance=request.user**).

2. Пробую написать **кастомный валидатор** для формы **clean_fieldname**:

```
class UserProfileEdit(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=100, label='Введите имя пользователя',
                               help_text='максимум 150 символов',
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False, label='Email', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email')
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if not email:
            email == * как передать существующий email? *
        return email
```

Но не могу сообразить, как в него передать данные по текущему пользователю, например его текущий email?

Как обычно перед вопросом перелопатил кучу всего, но решения для проблемы в таком контексте не нашел...

Поэтому вопроса вырисовывается сразу три, буду благодарен за ответ на любой из них, но для понимания предметной области, было бы круто, понять как это реализовать с разных сторон:

Цель изменять данные "имя" и "email" текущего пользователя, меняя *пустые* значения формы на *существующие данные пользователя*:

1. Если я меняю **cleaned_data** через вьюху (мб правильнее назвать это "контролер"?), то как передать **cleaned_data** в измененном виде, пользуюсь **ModelForm**?
2. Как передать текущего пользователя во вьюху, чтобы использовать просто **Form** (форму не связанную с моделью, для **ModelForm** это просто **instance=request.user**)?
3. Как реализовать **кастомный валидатор** для формы, думаю, туда нужно передать данные по текущему пользователю, но не понимаю как. (на мой взгляд это лучшее решение, для этого кастомные валидаторы и существуют же ;)

Модель для пользователя использую стандартную для **django - User**. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Эти строчки у тебя лишние, так как ты уж итак передаешь `instance=request.user`,
то в `cleaned_data` уже будут эти данные и если они пустые. то лишнее присваивание не поможет.

```
            if not form.cleaned_data['username']:     
                 form.cleaned_data['username'] = username
             if not form.cleaned_data['email']:
                 form.cleaned_data['email'] = useremail
            
            # нет смысла сохранять данные дважды
            # form.save()
```

у тебя проблема, в том, что данные пользователя ты подкидываешь, только когда идет post, а тебе еще нужно при заполнении формы изначально, тоже передавать текущие данные пользователя

```
 else:
        form = UserProfileEdit(instance=request.user)
```